# Can't sign report to get SHA1

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code, gradle, sha1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Uladzislau\Sparkco\sparkco\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\uladz.gradle\caches\7.6\scripts\dv46f4cmrgq0n1uvu9oootzoj).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 64

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

I read a lot of topics for the issue but didn't find a solution. Some of them ask me to change the gradle version of my app. But it seems like I can't do it.

[image]